# Making user.username (or any field) anonymous for certain users

Tags: django

I'm trying to make certain PII related attributes such as user.username or profile_picture anonymous for certain users.

I have a field in my database called *cant_see_pii* that tracks whether a user can see other users sensitive data.

```
class UserAttributes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'user_attribute')
    cant_see_pii = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default = False)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField("Profile Picture", default='images/default.svg', upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

If this field is true I want to obfuscate all other users pii related data, without hiding their own.

Example:
When a template has `<H1>{{other_user.username}}</H1>`, I want this to return `<H1>Anonymous User</H1>` or even better `<H1>Anonymous User 12345</H1>`

I don't want to have to do this for every instance I use this in every template so something like this won't work:
`<H1>{% if userattribute.cant_see_pii == True %}Anonymous User{%else%}{{other_user.username}}{%endif%}</H1>`

Comment: It seems to me that it would be better to separate the logic from the template. The first thing that came to my mind was to set the access from the model or controller level, depending on whether the user provides data.

Comment: @ttt Yes, seperating this logic from the template is a must as there are a great many occurances of these datapoints throughout the template codebase. It seems context processors re Sam's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Although potentially something on the model would be better as this field when it gets to the template isn't always called 'other_user.username'. I'm not yet sure of a way of overriding this on the default user model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a use case for a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

create a custom_context_processors.py

```
def anonymise_others(request):
    if request.user.user_attribute.cant_see_pii:
        return {
           "other_user.username": "Anonymous User",
           "other_user.profile_picture": "images/default.svg"
        }
```

Then include it in your settings.py TEMPLATES options list (at the end)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND":, #blanked
        "DIRS": ,  #blanked
        "APP_DIRS":,  #blanked
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "myApp.custom_context_processors.anonymise_others",
            ], 
        },
    },
]
```

I haven't added a number at the end. If you want one, I'd suggest adding code to create a random number, then building a string with it at the end. Otherwise a number and a username could be functionally equivalent, and the user would no longer be anonymous.

Comment: Thank you, I really custom processors as they're such a neat solution. However there are a couple of difficulties with this as the other user's usernames aren't soley exposed as 'other_user.username' within templates. Sometimes they are given different names in  for loops eg '{% for person in user_list %}{{ person.username }}{% endfor %}' or declared in responses to json requests. I'm thinking it might be possible to do something at the model layer..

Comment: Other options would be to create a specialised get_username_or_anon(request): method on the model or create a tag filter to use in templates. The method would have to be called in your view, rather than your template, as you'd need to pass the request in order to get the request user to test for the cant_see_pii boolean (same if you looped through querysets).  The template tag involves touching every template that used them, so they both have tradeoffs.  Alternately, you can add other formulations to the context_procecessor, eg, "person.username": "Anonymous User" without too much effort.